# Install WAIK installation images over PXE

Tags: windows-7, automation, deployment, pxe, waik

I setup a PXE Server and use it to serve some tools and live systems over the network (Setup with *Debian Wheezy*, *tftpd-hpa*, *isc-dhcpd* and *nfs-kernel-server*) and would like to deploy Windows Installations Images (created with *WAIK* + *Autounattend.xml*) over this PXE Server.
As far as I read I do need a *WinPE* to kick the installation off, which requires interaction.
 Is there a way to boot and start the image directly or to start WinPE and the installation automaticly?
WinPE over PXE is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with WinPE.

There is a file called `startnet.cmd` which will run when WinPE starts. Just edit this batch file according to your needs.

A simple example would be:

```
wpeinit
net use z: \\server\share /u:domain\user password
diskpart /s format.txt
dism /apply-image /imagefile:z:\customimage.wim /index:1 /applydir:w:\
bcdboot w:\windows /s w:\
exit
```

And contents of format.txt would be:

```
sel dis 0
clean
cre par pri
for fs=ntfs quick
assign letter=W
active
exit
```

In order to edit startnet.cmd:

1. Mount \sources\boot.wim to a temporary folder. Let's say C:\temp
2. Open `C:\Temp\Windows\System32\startnet.cmd` and edit contents. Also `format.txt` should be in this folder.
3. Unmount and commit changes.